# Heat problems for STM32F103C8T6 in enclosure

Tags: power, stm32, enclosure

For my hobby project, I'm intending to add a STM32F103C8T6 (and later STM32F407VET6 or ZET6) into an enclosure.

For worst case case, let's take the 407, the datasheet can be found [here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/ef/92/76/6d/bb/c2/4f/f7/DM00037051.pdf/files/DM00037051.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00037051.pdf).

On page 80, there are stated some power dissipations (between 435 and 543 mW).
Also some temperatures are shown on the page.

What I want to use in them (maybe spread over two devices, but let's assume I put everything in one STM32):

- Reset button
- Maximum 10 small LEDS (3mm, some bicolor). if these will cause too much power/heat I want to use smaller ones or less. Also the LEDs will be very sparsely on probably (at least most of them). They are for notification only. I would assume a total power consumption of 100 mA (assuming some are one more than others, so assuming 20 mA per LED, on average 5 are on).
- A few dozen ferrite beads
- 4 or 5 6N137 or similar optocouplers
- CAN bus driver (MCP2551 breakout board)
- One or two (2.4 GHz transceivers)

Used peripherals:

- 6-8 UARTs
- CAN
- Some timers
- One or two SPI ports (for the nRF24L01s)
- CAN

Environment/Boundaries

- No low power mode
- Maximum CPU frequency (168 MHz for STM32F407)
- Enclosure !

Would I get in trouble putting these STM32 in an enclosure ... I assume I need to add some holes possibly? What other measurements should I take to prevent them frying in their enclosure?

(note: I know I can probably calculate the exact power consumption, but I want to have a general idea about what I can expect, since I never have built a real project, and the only time I put an Arduino in an enclosure it got fried, but it was connected with a 12V adapter).

Comment: Are you talking about driving the LEDs directly from pins, or with transistors/drivers? The former would be the most likely to cause issues. I've designed many many micros like this, including several F103s into enclosures and never had any sort of issue, not sure they've ever even got that warm.  If your Arduino got fried running from 12V I assume that must have been because of a linear voltage reg, which is a completely different matter.

Comment: @DiBosco ... I was planning to drive them directly from pins. Because there are only 10 (some bicolor), so let's say 15 pins. It's only for indication, so I don't need the full power even (I can go for 20 mA to be on the safe side anyway). 
My Arduino was probably the voltage reg, but haven't tried to check if the chip itself is still usable.

I assume you made holes in the enclosure?

Comment: 15 pins at 20mA is 300mA maximum you're expecting the micro to sink or source. Look at Table 7. Current characteristics. Then have another think about what you're going to do. ;~) In the end you always *do* have to look at these things.

Comment: As far as holes in the enclosure goes, there have probably always been holes for I/O, but I'm struggling to think of an occasion where I needed specific air holes. However, it really depends on the environment it goes in and how well sealed the box is. If you have fifteen LEDs, are there holes for them for the user to see in and see said LEDs?

Comment: `Look at Table 7.` Tables are boring :D

Comment: @DiBosco .. I know 15 times 20 mA is 300 mA and that's quite a lot... but they will not be on continuously (although I have to admit it is possible). So maybe I should make a round robin algorithm to have only 1 one at a time (thus less bright if multiples are on). That would give me a 20 mA max (or 40 mA if I will keep two on max at the same time).

Comment: @DiBosco You mean that even though the holes will be 'filled' with LEDs, and connectors, some air will go out through them anyway? I was planning to 'glue' the LEDs, so that would fill the holes for LEDs.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers What happens if your software crashes with them all on? For the tiny cost of a load of 2N7002s I know what I'd do.

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks ... I assume you mean item 2 specifically from table 7: 2. PC13, PC14, PC15 and PI8 are supplied through the power switch. Since the switch only sinks a limited amount of current
(3 mA), the use of GPIOs PC13 to PC15 and PI8 in output mode is limited:
- The speed should not exceed 2 MHz with a maximum load of 30 pF.
- These I/Os must not be used as a current source (e.g. to drive an LED).
?

Comment: @DiBosco ... never heard of that (2N7002) ... are they similar to darlington drivers like  ULN2803 ? ... everytime I ask a question someone proposes something I never heard about (which is good, I'm learning a lot this way).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers They're just SOT23 FETs. You could happily use BC847s and resistors or the wonderful ULN28xx drivers. Anything like that. Your round robin method would work too though assuming no crashes! On the subject of LED holes, yes that's what I meant. Finally on the table, max current souced/sunk through Vdd/Vss pins is 150mA.

Comment: @DiBosco ... (and I need to find a DIP kind of 2N7002, since I'm not confident at soldering smaller than DIP).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63980/discussion-between-dibosco-and-michel-keijzers).

Comment: @DiBosco ... thanks ... I have also BC847s, but since I need many the ULN drivers might be easier. And I would have to think about crashes. I'm a software engineer, but fully new to AVRs, so I need to do small things at a time. To make you laugh: yesterday I uploaded a program like 100 times in one evening to my STM.. I can do this 100 days before having to use another one since the Flash is 10K written.

Comment: Use high efficiency LEDs and drive them at a couple of mA each. They will be quite bright enough to see, and you have just saved 80mA

Comment: @DirkBruere I will use it but when needed. It seems they are quite expensive though (cannot get them from Aliexpress)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Surface mount LEDs are dirt cheap - expect to pay under $0.10 one off 
http://uk.farnell.com/kingbright/kph-1608sgc/led-green-12mcd-568nm-smd/dp/2426215

Comment: @DirkBruere I would have to check into that... I cannot solder SMD (I barely can solder DIP).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers If you stick to 1206 size components they are easier to solder than through hole stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your main goal is to keep the MCU (generally all parts) within its operating region.

For that you have to have to guesstimate the current needed for operation, the thermal resistance (which is hard) and the ambient temperature the device will operate in.

The power dissipation figures you find in the datasheet are numbers which will prevent the junction temperature to go out of spec at the given ambient temperature.

---

So worst case, everything on, 3.6 V running full speed, they give 109 mA. This is 392 mW.

You are limited to 240 mA max through Vdd or Vss. 109 mA end up in the core, leaves 131 mA for the rest.

With modern LEDs I would not drive them with more than 5 mA as indicators, except they are used outside in sunlight.

Driving 10 LEDs with 5 mA and 0.4 V internal drop (table 49) adds another 20 mW to the internal dissipation.

Not sure about the other I/O ports. But lets assume a 450 mW power dissipation.

Table 98 has the thermal resistance for the packages listed. With the worst one you have 46 K/W.

With 450 mW you get a rise of 20 K of the junction temperature over the ambient (ambient of the MCU not the enclosure). That means you basically can have 85 °C inside your enclosure and the MCU would be fine. (84,3 °C to be precise)

---

Modeling what temperature will result in your enclosure is much harder. You need to know how the heat will transfer from the air to the enclosure and then from enclosure to ambient again - maybe your enclosure gives a number but most don't.

What I usually do is estimate the total power dissipation (add some extra), place a PCB inside the enclosure and solder a part on it which is able to handle the dissipation.

Then measure the ambient temperature, the temperature of the enclosure and the temperature inside the enclosure while powering the device. After some hours the temperatures will have stabilized and you can see what rise above ambient you get. If it's something like 40 K rise of the inside temperature, you can't use your device in temperatures above 45 °C. Because then, the ambient temperature of the MCU would be above 85 °C.

---

If you want to have some safeguards, you can use the internal temperature sensor of the MCU to shutdown in case of overtemperature.

There are some ICs around which will do the same and probably more accurate if you don't trust the internal sensor.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer ... I think it will be a good exercise for me to see if I also can find those numbers in the spec.

Very nice idea to check the IC temperature. Although in a r/l situation I wouldn't like it to power down, I can use it while testing and get an idea if I run into problems.

Comment: If you don't want to power down and temperature is a problem, you have to get better cooling. You don't need holes for that (if holes are a problem), you can use a good thermal conductor and connect the enclosure to heating ICs, so the enclosure becomes a better cooler.

Comment: I don't know yet if temperature will be a problem (no experience with temperature regarding microcontrollers, neither with enclosures). I will check how a thermal conductor looks like.
I don't think I can connect the heating IC to the enclosure, because it is an STM and the IC is a bit 'inside' if you know what I mean.

Comment: Well you basically just need a strip of aluminium or copper and a thermal glue on both ends and your thermal conductor is done :D

Comment: That sounds easier than it sounds :-) ... thanks for the clarification